# How to use map and reduce in pyspark for list object with some list variables?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have code below. Suppose I have 3 transactions: t1="1 3 4:80:20 25 35", t2="1 2:45:20 25", t3="1:10:10". I want output something like this 1=>50, 2=>25, 3=>25, 4=>35. 1=>50 --> 1 is item name and 50 is total utility for item 1 in transaction. does anybody know how to do it?

```
class transaction:
  def __init__(self, line):
    splittedPart = line.split(":")
    items = [int(x) for x in (splittedPart[0].split(" "))]
    profits = [int(y) for y in (splittedPart[2].split(" "))]
    self.items = items
    self.utility = profits

def readFile():
  p1 = transaction("1 3 4:80:20 25 35")
  print(p1.items)
  print(p1.utility)

readFile()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

def readTxt():
  conf = SparkConf().setAppName("read text file in pyspark")
  sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

  lines = sc.textFile("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/a.txt", 5)
  print(lines.getNumPartitions())

  llist = lines.collect()
  for line in llist:
      print(line)
  
  listTransaction = lines.map(lambda x : transaction(x))
  listTransaction.persist()
  
  <<need some code here to map the distinct item and its total utility>>

readTxt()
```

Expected output:

```
{Item:totalUtility}
1:50
2:25
3:25
4:35
```

Comment: as an aside, what is the point of the pointless class variables, `items= []` and `utility = []` when you just shadow them with instance variables in `__init__`? `self.items = items`, `self.utility = profits`

Comment: yes yes, I can remove them @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: can you add a proper example, with expected output ? currently, it does not seems to be spark related at all ...

Comment: I have edited the question @Steven. I need to collect all distinct items from transactions, then I sum the utility for the same item.

Comment: why do you work with sparkcontext and not sparksession ?

Comment: I just followed example from internet source, why did you ask? @Steven

Comment: because the title of your question is about using `map` and `reduce`. But if you use SparkSession, you will have dataframes instead of rdd, and it will be easier to manipulate your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, replace your sparkContext with a sparkSession :

```py
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("yarn")
    .appName("read text file in pyspark")
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

then you can process your data with a proper dataframe :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

df = spark.read.format("text").load("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/a.txt")
df.show()
+-----------------+                                                             
|            value|
+-----------------+
|1 3 4:80:20 25 35|
|     1 2:45:20 25|
|          1:10:10|
+-----------------+

schm = T.ArrayType(
    T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("item", T.IntegerType(), True),
            T.StructField("utility", T.IntegerType(), True),
        ]
    )
)


@F.udf(schm)
def transform(line):
    items, _, utility = line.split(":")
    items = [int(i) for i in items.split()]
    utility = [int(i) for i in utility.split()]
    return zip(items, utility)


df.select(F.explode(transform(F.col("value"))).alias("v")).groupBy("v.item").agg(
    F.sum("v.utility").alias("utility")
).show()
+----+-------+                                                                  
|item|utility|
+----+-------+
|   1|     50|
|   3|     25|
|   4|     35|
|   2|     25|
+----+-------+
```

Comment: I got an error : " type object 'SparkSession' has no attribute 'getOrCreate'" for this line : "spark = SparkSession.getOrCreate(conf=conf)" what should I do @Steven

Comment: @Edd Sorry, made a mistake on this line. I edited the code, please check if it works for you. Change the `master` if you have something else than yarn.

Comment: Perfect, it is working now, thank you. btw, how if I want to sum the distinct items not based on the utility but based on middle value. For example, from transaction 1 -> 1 3 4:80:20 25 35. So 80 will be added into (let say transactionUtility) for items 1, 3 and 4? @Steven

Comment: @Edd Currently, the middle value is dropped. You need to extract it properly in the UDF and add it to the output schema of the udf.